# Other Options to Send E-mail Using PowerShell

Tags: php, email, powershell, outlook

I'm trying to send out E-mails using a PowerShell script, my company's Virus scan (McAfee) is blocking port 25.  I know that I can go into McAfee's setting and uncheck the "prevent mass E-mail.. option", I also know that I can call Outlook within my script to send E-mail while user is logged in (which is too intrusive).  My question is, is there any other way to send e-mails using PowerShell without using any of the options I mentioned above.

Thank you.

```
 $From = "name@name.com"
 $To = "name@name.com"
 $Body = Test" 
 $Subject2 = "Hi"
 $SMTPServer ="smtp.com"

Send-MailMessage -From $From -To $To -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -Subject $Subject1 -Body $Body'
```

---

```
$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$Mail = $Outlook.CreateItem(0)
$Mail.To = "name@name.com"
$Mail.Subject = "Hi"
$Mail.Body = "Hello"[System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Name
$Mail.Send() '
```

Comment: why is this tagged php?

Comment: Hello Dragon,  I tagged PHP because my other option if to output my findings via an intramet, since sending it Via an E-mail is blocked.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

### Use .NET classes

You could create a [MailMessage] object manually and send it with the [SmtpClient] class, but this may fall foul of the McAfee software in the same way that `Send-MailMessage` does.

```
$From = "name@name.com"
$To = "name@name.com"
$Body = "Test" 
$Subject2 = "Hi"
$SMTPServer ="smtp.com"

$message = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage $From, $To
$message.Subject = $Subject2
$message.Body = $Body

$smtpclient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SMTPServer)
$smtpclient.Send($message)
```

- http://exchangeserverpro.com/powershell-send-html-email/

### Use Exchange Web Services

In order to use EWS you will need the **Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll** file, which you may find somewhere such as the following:

- C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange\Web Services\1.0
- C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange\Web Services\2.2
- [Download from Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=35371)

An example function implementation of this from Mike Pfeiffer's blog is here (and linked below):

```
Function Send-EWSMailMessage {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  param(
    [Parameter(Position=0, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true, Mandatory=$true)]
    [Object]
    $PrimarySmtpAddress,

    [Parameter(Position=1, Mandatory=$true)]
    [System.String]
    $Subject,

    [Parameter(Position=2, Mandatory=$true)]
    [System.String]
    $Body
    )

  BEGIN {
    Add-Type -Path "C:\bin\Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll"
    $sid = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().User.Value
    $user = [ADSI]"LDAP://<SID=$sid>"
  }

  PROCESS {
    $service = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService
    $service.AutodiscoverUrl($user.Properties.mail)

    if($PrimarySmtpAddress -is [Microsoft.Exchange.Data.SmtpAddress]) {
      $Recipient = $PrimarySmtpAddress.ToString()
    } else {
      $Recipient = $PrimarySmtpAddress
    }

    $mail = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessage($service)
    $mail.Subject = $Subject
    $mail.Body = $Body

    [Void]$mail.ToRecipients.Add($Recipient)
    $mail.SendAndSaveCopy()
  }

  END {
  }
}
```

- [Sending Email with PowerShell and the EWS Managed API](http://mikepfeiffer.net/2010/04/sending-email-with-powershell-and-the-ews-managed-api/)

The following link may be useful, but isn't specifically aimed at PowerShell implementations:

- [Creating and sending email messages by using the EWS Managed API 2.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd633628(v=exchg.80).aspx)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer...  McAfee blocks it as well.  For the EWS, non of the PCs have EWS, and the script will be running on local PCs.  Thank you.

Comment: You could host the DLL file on a network share to save having to distribute it to all machines. It would be good to hear whether the approach works in principle at least.

Answer (score 0):

Does the SMTP server you are using support encrypted connection ? If so try:

```
Send-MailMessage -To $to -From $from -SmtpServer $smtp -UseSsl -Port "587"
```

I would test it but I don't have McAfee.

Comment: I tried this but it did not work, McAfee blocks it.  Thank you.

Comment: To be clear, the `-UseSsl` switch enforces a secure connection to the SMTP server; it does not encrypt the message itself. Once the message has been received by the mail relay, it will be processed just as any other.